# Массив и многопоточность

Tags: c++, многопоточность

программа запускает 2 потока

1 поток должен найти в заданном массиве количество парных и количество нечетных чисел.

2 поток должен посчитать количество чисел которые делятся нацело на 5 или 7

один из этих потоков в начале программы должен заполнить массив числами от 1 до 1000, это должен сделать один из трех потоков, то кто первым сможет захватить ресурс - массив(используя std::once_flag, std::call_once)

Функции я написала. Но я  не  знаю как сделать чтобы один поток заполнил рандомно. Нужна ваша помощь.

```
void evenOROdd(int* array)
{
int evenCount = 0;
int oddCount = 0;
size_t arraySize = sizeof(array) / sizeof(int);
for (int index = 0; index < arraySize; ++index)
{
    if ((array[index] % 2) != 0)
        ++evenCount;
    else if ((array[index] % 2) == 0)
        ++oddCount;
}
std::cout << "Even- " << evenCount << "\n";
std::cout << "Odd- " << oddCount << "\n";
}




void entireFiveOrSeven(int* array)
{
int count = 0;
size_t arraySize = sizeof(array) / sizeof(int);
for (int index = 0; index < arraySize; ++index)
{
    if ((((array[index] % 5) == 0)) || ((array[index] % 7) == 0))
        ++count;
}
std::cout << "EntireFiveOrSeven- " << count << "\n";
}


void randomValues() 
{
std::srand(time(0));
size_t array_size = 1000;
int* array = new int[array_size];
for (int index = 0; index < array_size; ++index)
    array[index] = (rand() % 999 + 1);
}



  int main()
  {
    static int randomValues = randomValues();
    std::thread t1(evenOROdd);
    std::thread t2(entireFiveOrSeven);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
  }
```

UPD:Переделала как в примере. Но Я  так и не пойму как можно как я  делать в меине  делать.

```
 std::once_flag flag;
 void randomValues() 
 {
    std::srand(time(0));
    size_t array_size = 1000;
    int* array = new int[array_size];
    std::call_once(flag, array);
    for (int index = 0; index < array_size; ++index)
       array[index] = (rand() % 999 + 1);
  }


 int main()
 {
std::thread t1(randomValues);
std::thread t2(randomValues);

std::thread t1(evenOROdd);
std::thread t2(entireFiveOrSeven);
t1.join();
t2.join();

return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Попробуйти изучить пример использования из этой статьи: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once

Comment: @Unick я так  люблю такие ответы кк у Вас... А по вашеому я пеед этим от куда документацию читала?!  Документацию я и сама умею найти. Другое дело не всегда понимаю как сделать.

Comment: Не относится к сути вопроса, но вот это `size_t arraySize = sizeof(array) / sizeof(int);` -- ошибка. Так можно вычислять размер только в точке, гда компилятор отводит память под массив (т.е. там, где в sizeof можно подставить **имя массива** (а не указатель)). У вас на 64-бит машине будет 2, а на 32-бит -- 1. В функцию вместе с массивом (указателем на его начало) надо передавать еще и его размер.

Comment: @Оксана-Волинець, по вашему коду видно, что call_once у вас нигде не используется. В примере есть вызов функции std::call_once(flag1, []() во всех тредах, хотя из-за call_once функция вызовится один раз. Немогли бы вы подробнее сформулировать вопрос, какие детали использования call_once и once_flag вам не понятны.

Comment: @Unick я уже  сделала и разобралася)

Comment: @Оксана-Волинець, вы можете написать своё решение в ответе для будущих поколений.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/782043/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C мое  решение и вопросы  которые сейчас возникли