# Массив с функциями и многопоточность

Tags: c++, массивы, многопоточность, функции

У меня есть функции, вывод на экран их результатов мне нужно  делать в `main`. Первая функция работает нормально и все правильно выводится, а вторая и третья - крэшатся. Что я  не  так  делаю? Если делать вывод в функциях, то все работает.  Но так как это многопоточность, то вывод получается не по порядку, и поэтому я решила вынести вывод в `main`.

```
std::once_flag flag;
const size_t arraySize = 1000;
int array[arraySize];
void fillWithRandomNumbers()
{
    std::srand(time(0));

    for (size_t index = 0; index < arraySize; ++index)
        array[index] = (rand() % 999 + 1);
}

void countEvenAndOddNumbers(int counter[2])
{
    std::call_once(flag, fillWithRandomNumbers);
    counter[0] = 0;
    counter[1] = 0;

    for (size_t index = 0; index < arraySize; ++index)
        ++counter[array[index] & 1];
}


int summ(int num)
{
    int sum = 0;

    while (num != 0)
    {
        sum += num % 10;
        num /= 10;
    }

    return sum;
}
void findDivisibleByThree(int* result, int* counter)
{
    std::call_once(flag, fillWithRandomNumbers);
    *counter = 0;

    for (size_t index = 0; index < arraySize; ++index)
    {
        if ((summ(index) % 3) == 0)
        {
            result[*counter] = array[index];
            ++*counter;
        }
    }
}

void countDivisibleByFiveOrSeven(int* count)
{
    std::call_once(flag, fillWithRandomNumbers);
    *count = 0;

    for (size_t index = 0; index < arraySize; ++index)
    {
        if ((((array[index] % 5) == 0)) || ((array[index] % 7) == 0))
            ++*count;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int array[arraySize];
    int counter[2];
    int* count;
    int* cou;
    std::thread t1(countEvenAndOddNumbers, counter);
    std::thread t2(findDivisibleByThree , array, cou);
    std::thread t3(countDivisibleByFiveOrSeven, count);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    std::cout << "Even- " << counter[0] << "\n";
    std::cout << "Odd- " << counter[1] << "\n";
    std::cout << "EntireThree- " << *array << "\n";
    std::cout << "EntireFiveOrSeven- " << count << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

UPD:

```
  int main()
  {
     int result[arraySize];
     int counter[2];
     int countByThree = 0;
     int countByFiveOrSeven = 0;
     std::thread t1(countEvenAndOddNumbers, counter);
     std::thread t2(findDivisibleByThree, result, &countByThree);
     std::thread t3(countDivisibleByFiveOrSeven, &countByFiveOrSeven);
     t1.join();
     t2.join();
     t3.join();

     std::cout << "Even- " << counter[0] << "\n";
     std::cout << "Odd- " << counter[1] << "\n";

     for (size_t index = 0; index < arraySize; ++index)
     {
         std::cout << "Array- " << result[index] << "\n";
     }
     std::cout << "findDivisibleByThree- " << countByThree <<  "\n";
     std::cout << "CountDivisibleByFiveOrSeven- " << countByFiveOrSeven << "\n";

     return 0;
  }
```

Comment: может std::mutex?

Comment: а, ну и sleep желательно...

Comment: @test123 причем тут мютекс? я  где то использую мютекс? нет. Меня  интересует правильно ли я сделала в меине вывод а  не слип и мютекс. я их не использую  тут.  поэтому  ваш ответ  не понятен мне)

Comment: >>я где то использую мютекс? нет. << дык я и говорю, может в этом и причина) Кто синхронизировать потоки за вас будет?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я что-то не пойму -

```
int* count;
int* cou;
```

А где вы выделяете память?
По-моему, вы пытаетесь писать в никуда, вернее, в не пойми куда...

```
int count = 0;
int cou = 0;
...
std::thread t2(findDivisibleByThree , array, &cou);
std::thread t3(countDivisibleByFiveOrSeven, &count);
```

Так будет лучше.

Ну, и, если я верно понимаю, то надо вот такой вывод:

```
std::cout << "EntireThree- " << cou << "\n";
```

Вот [работающий пример](https://ideone.com/itZBha).

Comment: хм... а дествительно тут я  тупанула.  так  пойдет int count[arraySize];
 int cou[arraySize]; ? но мне  не  нравится что я arraySize перадаю

Comment: А зачем вам массивы? Вы же просто используете их как акккумулятор - накапливате количество?

Comment: вы правы. Сделала как у вас. спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста :) Если все решилось - закрывайте вопрос. Да, заинтриговало - "Сделал" - это как, оговорка по Фрейду? :) А, вы уже поправились... :)

Comment: да я  толстый 50 летний  мужчина)

Comment: нет, мне  еще  нужно вывести на екран сам массив, я  делаю  так 
          for(size_t index = 0; index < arraySize; ++index)
   std::cout << "Array- " << array[index] << "\n";   но оно выводит  много раз одно  значение

Comment: то есть мне нужно вывести на екран массив с числами которій подходят с функции void findDivisibleByThree(int* result, int* counter)

Comment: Во-первых, толстый 50-летний мужик - это я:), а во-вторых - как я понимаю, у вас объявление     `int array[arraySize];` в `main()` конфликтует с глобальным `int array[arraySize];`. Вам точно нужны два *разных* массива с одним именем?

Comment: нет не нужны я в меине UPD сделала. Я  правильно  фором  проходжусь и вывожу  на екран.  Я уже просто всех запутала,  поэтому: я  хочу вывести на екран  массив  с  значенями  который подходят с функции findDivisibleByThree(int* result, int* counter) тоесть массив int* result, но у меня не выходит

Comment: Это? https://ideone.com/LFlsJR

Comment: не совсем. у Вас все выводится. а мне нужно чтобы выводились  только значения   которые подходят - то есть значения сумма которых  делится  на 3(то что я  делаю в функции findDivisibleByThree(int* result, int* counter) )

Comment: я посмотрела. походу  тут  у меня не правильно int result[arraySize];, так как arraySize а мне нужно только выводить те которые подходит, а я  больше выделяю памяти. как у вас в коде  до индекса 333  норм  значения  а дальше  мусор

Comment: Ну, думаю, тут уже разберетесь, что вам нужно, а что нет :) - добавьте `if (result[idx]%3==0)`

Comment: так як  это  делаю в функции  findDivisibleByThree(int* result, int* counter) эсли вы посмотрете. или тут  это тоже нужно  делать?